# How do production systems measure real-time latency in things like audio mixers and video processors?

Tags: gstreamer

This might be a bit broad of a question, so some suggested reading material would be helpful. For live audio mixers or video compositors, are there any standard ways to measure latency in production systems?

I can see how one would do glass-to-glass measurements using injected and read artifacts between say, WebRTC video endpoints.

However, say someone wanted to just monitor the health of the GStreamer application the cloud side (i.e. no visibility from clients using the pipeline). For example, let's say I wanted to setup an alarm that triggers if a production video compositing / processing pipeline breaks 50 ms of ingress/egress latency. What are the general ideas or solutions to problems of this sort?